# inotifywait does not work for one glob pattern, but works for others

Tags: command-line, bash

This is my scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

. Load

inotifywait -m \
/Base/Qwik/**/*.jsx \
/Project/Web/src/Components/**/*.jsx \
/Project/Web/src/routes/**/*.jsx \
/Project/Web/src/routes/*.jsx \
-r \
-e modify \
-e move \
-e create \
-e delete \
-q \
--exclude "Exports.jsx" |
while IFS=' ' read File Event
do
    export File
    export Event
    Info $File $Event
    node /Project/Web/AstGenerator.js $File
done
```

`inotifywait` works for all other paths, except the first path. And the glob pattern is correct. I can use `find /Base/Qwik/**/*.jsx` it shows me the list of a lot of files in that directory. I have also specified the `-r` flag for recursive operation.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: `**` doesn't do anything special on bash unless `globstar` is enabled, and `find` has nothing to do with the globs in `find /Base/Qwik/**/*.jsx`. In both cases, it's bash (or whichever shell you use to execute the script) that does the glob expansion.

Comment: @muru, but it works for other paths. And the other paths use globs. For example `/Project/Web/src/routes/about/ceo/index.jsx` is captured by this script.

Comment: Then you must be enabling `globstar` somewhere.

Comment: @muru, but why it does not work for that directory only? All of the directories are like each other. What can be different here?

Comment: That's hard to say, since you're not showing us what you're actually running. As I said, `globstar` must be enabled somewhere, but it's not in the code you have shown us, so whatever else you aren't showing us might be affecting things. You should run the script with `bash -x` and see what the debug output looks like.

Comment: It might help if you add the contents of the `Load` file that is sourced at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

> `inotifywait` works for all other paths, except the first path.  And the glob pattern is correct.

But only if the `globstar` extension is enabled.  Otherwise it might only sometimes work for the wrong reasons.

> I can use `find /Base/Qwik/**/*.jsx` it shows me the list of a lot of files in that directory.

Often `globstar` is enabled in `~/.bashrc` for interactive use in the shell, where you might be testing some of your globs, but this doesn't also switch it on inside any script you run.

You first need to switch it on inside the script with `shopt -s globstar` before it calls `inotifywait`.

---

> I have also specified the `-r` flag for recursive operation.

Recursion only applies to directories, not individual files.  It is pointless when you do things this way.

However `create`, `move`, and `delete` will only work for files in watched *directories*, not watched *files*, so I think you really wanted to watch only the top directories with the recursion flag.

I would recommend reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-a-directory-for-creation-of-files-of-a-specific which I think is similar to what you are trying to do.